# Forwarding multiple emails as attachment into a new email from excel vba

Tags: email-attachments, outlook

Can anyone help me with excel vba code to send multiple/specific emails that are present in my inbox as an attachment in a new mail to someone I want.

so basically what I am asking for is if I go to my outlook express inbox and select lets say three mails and then click on the forward button on the ribbon it will create a new mail item with the mails that were selected as an attachment. I want this to be automated from excel vba.

Please any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Premanshu

Comment: Show what you've attempted to do so far, and we'll (maybe) try help fix it. We are not here to bang out code for you, nor do your job for you.

Comment: Hi Marc, I am sorry I did not post any code with my question. Till my current project have only worked on core excel vba codes so had no idea about excel to outlook codes in vba. I searched some codes online before creating my post but none of them were related to my ask so did not post them. I am sorry if I sounded rude or unwilling to do my own job myself.

Comment: However I have finally found the answer to my question and will post my code in the answer section so that anyone else can refer to in case ever needed. I am new to online forum/community so please ignore if I made any mistake.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, yes this is for outlook express...

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer for my question after some more search from one online forum/community and have been able to modify that according to my need. Posting the code below for anyone's reference and also the link for the original post that I used and modified for my purpose.

```
Sub ForwardSelectedItems()

On Error Resume Next
Dim myolApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

If objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection.count = 0 Then
   MsgBox ("No item selected")
   Exit Sub
End If

For Each objItem In objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set objMsg = objItem.Forward()
    With objMsg
        .Display
        For Each itm In objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        .Attachments.Add itm, olEmbeddeditem
        Next itm
        .Subject = "example"
        .To = "example@example.com"
        .Body = “”
        .Send
    End With
Exit For
Next

Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing

End Sub
```

the link for the popst I refered to is:-
[Forwarding Outlook Item as attachment and adding it to a category in the same VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606625/forwarding-outlook-item-as-attachment-and-adding-it-to-a-category-in-the-same-vb)

Thank you all.
Regards,
Premanshu